# How to make an icon overlay an Image such that the icon remains in its place when the image is uploaded via javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create an app that has a feature that allows its users to upload images from their computer and that chosen image is displayed as preview. The problem I'm running into is that before the image is selected, an icon button is overlaid on the bottom-right of the image element and when the image is chosen the icon button is pushed off the image element. I want the icon button to stay in its place.

Here's the code pertaining to this part:

```
<div id="main-container">
     <section id="customer_archetype" style="width: 500px; margin: auto">
         <form method="post" action="./submit_form_data.php" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
           <div style="margin: auto;">
              <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: #E1E0E1; border-radius: 100px; ">
                   <img id= "uploaded_image" src="#" style="display:none; width: 150px; height: 150px; border-radius: 100px;" >
                   <input style="display:none" name = "archetype_image_input" id="archetype_image_input" type="file" accept="image/*">
                   <img src="./images/camera.png" id="cam_img" style="width:22px; height:22px; color:gray; z-index = 1; cursor: pointer ; margin-left:105px; margin-top: 125px;">
               </div>
              </div>    
              <div id = "input_fields" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin: 10px auto; width: 400px;">
           </div>
         </form>
         <div style="text-align: center;">
             <button style="width: 100px" id="add-input-field-btn">Add Field</button>
             <button id="remove-input-field-btn">Remove Field</button>
         </div>
     </section>
</div>
```

[image: The code that I have written for the image and icon button]

And here's the look of the output before the image is chosen:

[image: Picture of output before image is chosen]

Output after image is chosen. As you can see the icon is pushed off:

[image: Output after image is chosen]

Comment: Paste code as text, not image.

Comment: Give it high enough z-Index and position absolute

Comment: You can use `background-image` for `::before`  that!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the image container as `position: relative` and then with the icon (the camera image), set it to be `position: absolute`.

Don't use `margin` properties to place an image like this, it's subject to move as the DOM is changed.

[Here's a working example using your code](https://codepen.io/Lmonk72/pen/LYdVQPN). I've added classes to make viewing the styling easier.